# How can I create a limited edition item with various sizes but, only sell 50 total?

Tags: inventory, shopping-cart, stores

I want to sell limited edition prints of a specific image.

I want to offer various sizes of that specific image.

I only want to sell 50 total prints, regardless of size, of that specific image.

Is it possible to create a limited edition item in this manner? To set the inventory for the parent product but, not the various options that are available for that product?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to use a configurable product you could just use a simple product with your image size as a custom option. Then simply setting the inventory to 50 should be all that is needed.

[image: Product Setup]
[image: Frontend]

Comment: Ideally, I would like to offer configurable selections such as framing options. Everything is made on demand so, there is no real inventory to track for this product except the total number sold, to ensure I don't sell more than I'm limiting the run to.

Comment: So far this all sounds doable with a simple product. I have added a couple of screenshots of how you could use Custom Options and how this would look.

Comment: Thank you so much for the screen shots.I'll try playing around.

Answer (score 1):

May not be ideal answer, You need to create a simple product having an size option in which you will describe the image size and set qty of product to 50. It can be done with attribute or custom option also.

Comment: Would this work if I were to have other options, such as frame A and Frame B to pick from?  Thanks for input =)

Comment: You can manage as many attributes as you wish,they may or may not be dependent, custom options is another quick alternate